# Alternatives to AJAX function interval

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, chat

I have been creating a web based chat application using PHP, jQuery and AJAX. Methods that I've researched on use either a database or text file to store the individual messages users post, and use PHP to read or write on them. The PHP is called periodically every 'x' ms by the jQuery using an AJAX function set to the respective time interval.

See: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931

I wanted to ask if this interval could be removed by adding some sort of code that ran the PHP file whenever the database/ text file was updated?

Comment: You might consider looking into WebSockets, allowing for two-way communication between client and server (it's how SO notifications work), no need for intervals

Comment: I'd rather avoid using WebSockets. Is there an alternative using only PHP/JavaScript?

Comment: There's also XMPP standard, please take a look https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/tutorials/x-realtimeXMPPtut/ but I would go with pusher.js, it's so much easier